# Progressive Web Apps (do not suggest reinstalling the button)?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm taking the first steps in developing my Progressive Web Apps.
I ask for help or tell me where to read the instructions and manuals.

Here is my example of Web Appress: https://goba2000.github.io/rpapp/
My repository on GITHUB: https://github.com/goba2000/rpapp

Question:
I go from cell phone to Android to my website https://goba2000.github.io/rpapp/
On the site at the click of the button "ADD" I propose to install the Web Apps application. I refuse the installation. Again, I publish the site, and already when I click the "ADD" button again, the Web Apps application does not install (via the Google Chrome properties - "add to the main screen" I can install the Web Apps application anytime).

To again be able to add the Web Apps application via the "ADD" button, I have to clear all data and cookies in the browser in the settings of the site https://goba2000.github.io/rpapp/.

1. How to make that the button "ADD" the application could be installed several times?
2. What browsers support Progressive Web Apps?

Answer (score 0):

How to make that the button "ADD" the application could be installed several times?

Check the [The New and Improved Add to Home screen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen)

What browsers support Progressive Web Apps?

- Chrome (this is given)
- [Safari](https://medium.com/awebdeveloper/progressive-web-apps-pwas-are-coming-to-a-safari-near-you-216812aba5a)
- [Edge on Windows 10](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/135665/pwas-coming-windows-store-windows-10-version-1803)
- [Firefox](https://www.lumavate.com/blog/firefox-support-progressive-web-apps/)
- [Opera](https://dev.opera.com/blog/pwa-taipei/)

pretty much all browsers will be supporting PWA, as this is the future.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user refuses to install the app, Chrome wont let you prompt the user multiple times. As you have mentioned yourself, if user have changed his mind about installation, he can do so by clicking on "Add to Home Screen" option from the menu.

If you think of users perspective, it will be less annoying when sites are not repeatedly prompting me to add to home screen when I have chosen to not do so in the first place. So the Chrome's behavior is built that way.

This is the current behavior(as of Apr-2018) and as a developer we don't have anything to do about it, except you can put a block of message in your screen requesting user to add it though "Add to home screen".

Browser support is already addressed in the other answer. so I'm leaving that from duplicating.